# How to use lots of bitmaps in a game without exceeding VM memory budget?

Tags: android, animation, bitmap

In my game i have 12 different animations and each animation consist of 10 bitmaps and each bitmap is 200x150 pixel. Every time user touches to the screen(virtual gamepad) one of the animations will play. Normally this is an easy job but performance wise i am having trouble. Loading all bitmaps on an array from the beginning of the game cause to crash game because of VM memory budget problem. It seems
my other option is to recreate bitmaps everytime i need and then recyle them, but this might cause lag because of creating time and garbage collection. I can't think of third option so i am asking you. Is there any memory efficient and not laggy option ?

Comment: you should either reduce bitmap formap (if you can) to something like rgb565 or even palette256, or load animations at play time.

Comment: @fazo: The resolution on his images seem reasonable (even for mobile) but I would be afraid to recommend 16bit color due to image quality and it only reduces the space needed by 50%. Palette256 is even more limiting quality but does reduce the size a lot.

Comment: 16 bits are very popular, and you don't loose much of quality especially with proper dithering). Also we don't know what those animations look like, so it's hard from suggesting anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's 14MB of memory for your animations which might be a lot for the VM heap it should fit nicely into the graphics card memory. I am assuming that you are using OpenGL (if not you will almost have to). In which case you can build your frames one-by-one, bind them to a texture and release them from the VM's memtory. This will be fairly fast but I wouldn't do it often or offer some sort of loading feature if the lag is greater than 1/2 second or so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not using OpenGL. Since my game is 2d and only playing some animations i thought surfaceview would do Ok. As it is obvious i am just new to game programming so could you explain me why do i almost have to use OpenGL ?

Comment: There are a number of reasons but as you have discovered, heap memory is one. The other is the CPU strain needed for rendering graphics at above even 20fps is very high (especially with animations). OpenGL isn't just for 3D graphics it's for all high performance graphics. Even a game as simple as, Hexaddicus  (http://www.sharpermindstech.com/hexaddicus/) a simple 2D game I worked on, required OpenGL to get the needed performance.

Comment: I will use OpenGL then. Your game looks really nice i will try in a few min. Thanks again.

Comment: @AndrewWhite Your link doesn't work for me. I assume this is the game: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sharpermindstech.android.hexaddicus

Comment: @Pius indeed, that is the link; SharperMindsTech is no more but the app is still live. Unfortunately I can't edit comments.

Answer (score -1):

I would consider using a SpriteSheet for this. SpriteSheet would contain all the frames of the animation on one bitmap, and you can then programatically load the correct frame coordinates to create your animation.