# Create animated splash screen using frames on Android

Tags: android, animation, frame, out-of-memory, splash-screen

So here's the deal, I've searched every single question and link online but none are helpful.
I have 120 frames of an animation in .jpg format for my splash screen. I understand that jpegs are converted to bitmaps on memory so that's why I get an OutOfMemoryError. The maximum frames I get to animate are 10. Is there any way to do this frame by frame, or should I try something else. Here's my code:

```
    final AnimationDrawable anim = new AnimationDrawable();
    anim.setOneShot(true);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 120; i++) 
    {
        Drawable logo = getResources().getDrawable(getResources()
                  .getIdentifier("l"+i, "drawable", getPackageName()));

        anim.addFrame(logo, 50);
        if (i % 3 == 0)
        {
            System.gc();
        }
    }

    ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.SplashImageView);
    myImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(anim);
    myImageView.post(new Runnable()
    {
       public void run()
       {
          anim.start();
       }
    });
```

I've placed the 120 jpegs under the drawable folder with an "l" prefix (eg l1, l2 etc).
I do garbage collection every 3 jpegs but that won't do a thing.

Comment: Did you try using an Animation-List in xml?

Comment: Yes... It was really painful copy-pasting 120 times "almost" the same thing. (I'm stupid enough not to try with a few jpegs before)

Comment: 120 frames are too much for any animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to do it without `AnimationDrawable` using `Handler.postDelayed`. Something like this:

```
final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.SplashImageView);
final Handler handler = new Handler();

final Runnable animation = new Runnable() {
    private static final int MAX = 120;
    private static final int DELAY = 50;

    private int current = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final Resources resources = getResources();
        final int id = resources.getIdentifier("l" + current, "drawable", getPackageName());
        final Drawable drawable = resources.getDrawable(id);

        image.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
        handler.postDelayed(this, DELAY);
        current = (current + 1) % MAX;
    }
};

handler.post(animation);
```

This solution requires less memory because it keeps only one drawable at the time.

You can cancel the animation using `handler.removeCallbacks(animation);`.

If you want make a one-shot animation you can call `handler.postDelayed` conditionally:

```
if (current != MAX - 1) {
    handler.postDelayed(this, DELAY);
}
```

Comment: That is ALMOST exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot. Although it is laggy and the frames resolution is really bad.

Comment: this code doesn't do anything with frame resolution, so you should probably use frames with better quality. Or try to use `setImageDrawable` instead of `setBackgroundDrawable`

Comment: Another silly question. How do I make it stop? It runs infinitely and as a result I get an error for not finding the resource (l121 does not exist)

Comment: hmmm... you shouldn't get this error... anyway, check my update answer, it might help you

Answer (score 1):

Y̶o̶u̶ ̶n̶e̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶c̶a̶l̶l̶ ̶.̶r̶e̶c̶y̶c̶l̶e̶(̶)̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶b̶i̶t̶m̶a̶p̶s̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶d̶o̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶a̶n̶y̶m̶o̶r̶e̶.̶ ̶O̶t̶h̶e̶r̶w̶i̶s̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶y̶ ̶w̶o̶n̶t̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶g̶a̶r̶b̶a̶g̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶l̶l̶e̶c̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶p̶e̶r̶l̶y̶.̶

Also in the manifest set uses large heap to true. This gives you a bit more space to breathe. >)

Comment: Can you be more specific? How do I call recycle once the AnimationDrawable has "started()" ?

Comment: Ah, my bad. Sorry I need a coffee :) Didn't look right. You are using drawables not bitmaps. No need to call recycle on those. Sorry..

Comment: Mmm... you might have to use openGL for your splash screen as this post suggests: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136385/how-to-use-lots-of-bitmaps-in-a-game-without-exceeding-vm-memory-budget

Answer (score 1):

i tried all of those solution with each one getting better :D i could use  more frame and more resolution but still not satisfying to managers :( i found best solution is to use video instead of frames it works like a charm for  even low memory devices i tested 150 frames each of size 480*854 with a video codec (H.264 mp4) on xperia u with 256mb of ram