# How do I iterate over a large number of resources with similar names?

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm currently trying to start a thread which fetches a drawable from its resources and posts it after a set amount of time. Then fetches the next drawable from resources and does the same thing all over.

```
    final ImageView zImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.zzz_animation_view);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 1; i<=510; i++)
            {
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.z_animation0001); // how do I increment this recourse to z_animation0002, 0003, ..., 0510 ?
                zImageView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        zImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                },200);
            }

        }
    }).start();
```

Firstly. Is this a proper way of approaching the problem? The drawables are too large for me to use animation-list and as such my goal is to load the images one at a time to ensure that I have enough memory. Secondly how do I solve the problem of iterating over my resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get resource id by its name using [`Resources.getIdentifier`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) :

```
final int current = 5;
final String pattern = "z_animation%04d";
final String name = String.format(pattern, current);
final int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName());
final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), id);
```

Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340372/create-animated-splash-screen-using-frames-on-android/14340906#14340906) you can find my answer for the same question with code sample that does exactly what you want.

Comment: However, `Resources.getIdentifier` is really slow, because it uses heavy reflection (I assume). When using that many drawables I would strongly suggest not to use it.

Comment: Thanks. this is perfect. One question though: How memory intensive is this? Is there any need for me to clean up the heap while performing this task?

Comment: @Thrakbad just checked `getIdentifier` realization. It doesn't use reflection and implemented in native code, so I think you shouldn't worry about its performance. Anyway, most of the execution time will be consumed by `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` and it actually doesn't matter how `getIdentifier` implemented.

Comment: @litemode it uses really small amount of memory because there is only one `Drawable` instance at a time.

Comment: @Thrakbad, oh the irony, reflection works even faster than `getIdentifier` http://daniel-codes.blogspot.ru/2009/12/dynamically-retrieving-resources-in.html

Answer (score 0):

I would put the images in the assets folder and load them from there as described here: https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/store-and-use-files-in-assets/

In the assets folder you can just add a number to the file name.