# Is it possible to animate the bitmap in Android Splash Screen?

Tags: android, animation, splash-screen

I have implemented a splash screen for my android app which doesn't have a layout, instead, we are setting the splash screen image through the theme (window background). So is it possible to do an animation where there is no layout available?

Comment: what kind of animation you want to perform? can you give some specifics?

Comment: it is not possible to animate that drawable object directly , but you could do it , after activity is created completely then set the layout of exact same as drawable and animate the object you wouldn't feel the difference, i am doing same in one of my project's and it works great

Comment: refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340372/create-animated-splash-screen-using-frames-on-android?rq=1

Comment: I had done the same but when implementing this in xamarin forms it creates additional delay for the initial launch.